# Telegram bots require an @ to receive commands after another bot sends a message

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I am in a group chat with multiple bots.

The first has access to all messages, and listens for a `keyword`. When a chat message contains the `keyword`, it sends a message. For example:

```
[Navigatron]: This message contains the keyword
[Keyword Bot]: Hello World!
```

The second bot does not have access to all messages, and listens for the commands `/r` or `/r@botname`. When this happens, it sends a random quote.

```
[Navigatron]: /r
[Quote bot]: Hello World!
```

Whenever the keyword bot sends a message, the quote bot stops responding to `/r` commands. It will still respond to `/r@botname` commands, and then afterwards will respond to `/r` commands again.

Other bots also stop responding to the short-form commands. "Waking up" one bot with `/command@bot` does not "wake up" any others.

For example: (Lines starting with # are comments)

```
# Short commands work
[Navigatron]: /command1
[Bot 1]: Output 1
# Triggering the keyword bot
[Navigatron]: This message contains the keyword
[Keyword bot]: Hello world!
# Short commands no longer work
[Navigatron]: /command1
[Navigatron]: /command2
# Using a "long" command "wakes up" only one bot
[Navigatron]: /command1@bot1
[Bot 1]: Output 1
[Navigatron]: /command1
[Bot 1]: Output 1
[Navigatron]: /command2
# Each additional bot must be "woken up" individually
[Navigatron]: /command2@bot2
[Bot 2]: Output 2
[Navigatron]: /command2
[Bot 2]: Output 2
```

I would expect / would like all the non-keyword bots to continue responding to short commands, even after the keyword bot sends a message.

There are 6 bots in the channel. I am the author of some of them. Some use nodejs, some use python, some use webhooks, some use polling - the keyword bot "breaks" all of them. For this reason, I suspect that this is not a problem with any individual bot, but likely an issue in telegram itself.

Comment: As far as I know I don't think bot and bot can talk to each other. Try to create a group and get the bots to be in the group. Get the bot to send message to the group in instead to a bot. I have not try this out but I guess its worth trying.

Comment: Hi @Wahsei, thank you for your comment. I'm afraid the issue is that they already are in a group, and while they shouldn't have any effect on each other, they do - they can't see each others messages, but it also looks like they can't see human messages either after another bot sends a message (until they're reset with an @ command)